# Convergence of $\int_1^7 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Is $$\int_1^7 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}}\ dx < \infty \ ?$$ Should I use asymptotic criterium? It's the only thing that comes to my mind, but I can't find suitable function...

Comment: Yes. Factor $x^2-1$, ignore (read deal with it) the well-behaved factor and analyze $(x-1)^{1/3}$ around $1$ (or $t^{1/3}$ around $0$). [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/287265).

Comment: Alternatively, you can use $x^2\geqslant x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only are of concern is, of course, near $x=1$. Let $u=x^2-1$; then 
$dx = \frac{du}{2\sqrt{u+1}}$. The integral has tranformed to 
$$
\int_{0}^{48} \frac{u^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{2\sqrt{u+1}} du
$$
The behavior of $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u+1}}$ for $u$ near zero is $\frac{1}{2} + O(u)$ so the behavior of the integral is like that of 
$$
\int_{0}^{x} \frac{u^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{2} du
$$
which for small positive $x$ goes like $\frac{3}{4}x^{+\frac{2}{3}}$.  Since that exponent is positive, the contribution to the original interval of the region very near zero is zero, and the original integral converges.