# Convergence of $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Please help me to prove that this integral converges.

$$\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}}\ dx $$

No ideas. Tried to find function which is bigger and converges, equivalent fun-s, but no result still.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/287265).

Comment: But in this case we have $x^3$ in denominator, so these theorems do not apply as I understand.

Comment: Try the binomial series.

Comment: @user156707 See my comment [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819589/convergence-of-int-17-frac1-sqrt3x2-1-dx?lq=1#comment1693920_819589). Use the same techniques.

Answer (score 3):

Using the factorization $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab +b^2) $, rewrite the integral as

$$\int_0^1 dx \, \frac{(1-x)^{-1/3}}{(1+x+x^2)^{1/3}} $$

Sub $y=1-x$ and observe that

$$\int dy \, y^{-1/3} = \frac{3}{2} y^{2/3} + C$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $\sqrt{1-x^2}<\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}<1$ for $x\in(0,1)$.